# Why isn't using FindIndex() and returning early from iterating faster than FindAll()?

Tags: c#, list

The match condition I need to have tested on list items is time-consuming. Moreover, I know that the condition will be matched for no more than 3 items of the list.

So, checking all list items could not be the best idea; however, when I tried to use `FindFindex()` method at most for 3 times, the test took more than those of cases I used `FindAll()` and `Where()`.

How can I speed up this method, or find at most three matches faster?

```
| #  Method            Time (sec)
| -------------------------------
| 1   Find (one-by-one)   42.37
| 2   FindAll             30.17
| 3   Where               30.53
```

**Method #1:**

```
{
    int index;
    Predicate<T> predicate = t =>
        {
            ...
        };

    index = myCollection.FindIndex(predicate);

    if (index != -1)
    {
        T t1 = myCollection[index];
        myCollection.RemoveAt(index);

        index = myCollection.FindIndex(predicate);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            T t2 = myCollection[index];
            myCollection.RemoveAt(index);

            index = myCollection.FindIndex(predicate);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                T t3 = myCollection[index];

                return new T[] { t1, t2, t3 };
            }
            else
            {
                return new T[] { t1, t2 };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new T[] { t1 };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new T[] { };
    }
}
```

**Method #2:**

```
{
    return myCollection.FindAll(t =>
    {
        ...
    }).ToArray();
}
```

**Method #3:**

```
{
    return myCollection.Where(t =>
    {
        ...
    }).ToArray();
}
```

***EDIT:*** **Modified Method #1:**

```
{
    int index;
    Predicate<T> predicate = t =>
        {
            ...
        };

    index = myCollection.FindIndex(predicate);

    if (index != -1)
    {
        T t1 = myCollection[index];

        index = myCollection.FindIndex(index + 1, predicate);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            T t2 = myCollection[index];

            index = myCollection.FindIndex(index + 1, predicate);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                T t3 = myCollection[index];

                return new T[] { t1, t2, t3 };
            }
            else
            {
                return new T[] { t1, t2 };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new T[] { t1 };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new T[] { };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the "Where" instead?

Comment: @User2012384, I used it. The methods #2 and #3 are quite similar to each other.

Comment: You don't have to remove the items in your first method. You could use `public int FindIndex(  int startIndex,  Predicate<T> match )`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanielS, thanks for your comment. I applied it and it took 30.97 sec. It's not faster than `FindAll` nor `Where` yet.

Comment: I don't see method #3/3

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna add it explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your way is slower because it iterates over the entire collection three times, and because you do the removal operations which also come at a penalty (of *"O(n), where n is (Count - index)"*, [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You can evade both by calling [`FindIndex(int, predicate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx) overload instead, where the `int` denounces the start position in iterating the source collection.

So replace both places where this occurs:

```
myCollection.RemoveAt(index);

index = myCollection.FindIndex(predicate);
```

With this:

```
index = myCollection.FindIndex(index + 1, predicate)
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding DanielS's comment and your answer, I changed the code and could not achieve a faster result than that of `FindAll`. Shall it be assumed as the fastest way?

Comment: All methods now come down to the same: iterate over the collection and find objects that match the predicate. Best-case, yours should be faster - if many elements match the predicate, and if they're at the beginning. If a lot of your data contains less than three matches, all methods have to iterate the entire collection anyway and will take just as long.

Answer (score 2):

As long as List is used, there's no way but to iterate through collection. You can modify #3 like below:

```
return myCollection.Where(...).Take(3).ToArray();
```

ToArray will start iteration, and take 3 will limit iteration to stop after 3 results. Which is practically the same thing with your #1 (modified) example.

EDIT:

Below is Linqpad test program about Take's working behaviour:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Something>();
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        list.Add(new Something { Value = i });

    var result = list.Where(p => p.Value < 50).Take(3);
    result.Count().Dump();
}

public class Something
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value 
    {
        get { _value.Dump(); return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

And test results:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Last one is collection count, only 3 items are enumerated.

Comment: I don't agree. Why do you think it limits `Where` function to match the first three cases? To me, appending `Take` method to `Where` will take effect after `Where` operation is done.

Comment: Unless you enumerate the collection before Take method like *Where(..).ToList().Take(3)* it works as I said. Linq expressions are joined to do so, they are not executed as you call them.

Comment: Great! I am convinced.